# Snow Leopard - Open With - edit recommended applications

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard

I thought one of the new features of snow leopard was supposed to be the ability to clean up contextual menus.  I know it does with the services.  But I thought you would be able to edit the "Open With" menu.  Does anyone know how to do this?

I don't want 20+ applications to open up images (especially not XCode).  I just want the menu to contain the 3 or 4 that I actually use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you may be referring to is Snow Leopard's ditching of type and creator codes for Uniform Type Identifiers, which there's some detail about [here](http://arstechnica.com/staff/fatbits/2009/09/metadata-madness.ars) and [here](http://www.appleinsider.com/articles/09/09/22/inside_snow_leopards_uti_apple_fixes_the_creator_code.html).  It doesn't do exactly what you're asking about here, although it certainly influences what application ends up getting started by Launch Services to open a file.

That said, there are some 3rd party utilities that might do something similar to what you're looking for (though not exactly what you're requesting) like [Magic Launch](http://michelf.com/software/magic-launch/) or [LaunchCodes](http://pagehand.com/launchcodes/).  There might be some other ways to hack/modify the Launch Services database yourself w/o a piece of shareware, but I'm not aware of them.

You might also be interested in [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/20822/where-does-mac-os-x-store-file-association-information).

To do exactly what you're asking for, I think what you'd actually have to do is [modify the Info.plist](http://developer.apple.com/macosx/uniformtypeidentifiers.html) within each of the applications you don't want on the list, and then [rebuild the Launch Services database](http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20031215144430486).

Comment: Thank you for all the links.  I wish their was an easier way to do it than modify the info.plist for each file, but I guess that's what I'll have to do to clean it up.